# Adding a container to a Sliver

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I just started to learn about slivers and they don't seem to work with any other Flutter widgets except for the ones that start with "Sliver". I tried adding a `Container` so I can add `BorderRadius` to decorate the list. But I got this error:

> A RenderSliverFillRemaining expected a child of type RenderBox but
>   received a child of type RenderSliverToBoxAdapter.

Here's my code so far:

```
...
SliverFillRemaining(
  child: SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(36),
          topRight: Radius.circular(36),
        ),
      ),
      child: SliverPadding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 50.0,
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                child: Text('List Item $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
...
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved my issue by using a `NestedScrollView` instead of a `CustomScrollView`.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          floating: false,
          pinned: true,
          snap: false,
          elevation: 0,
          expandedHeight: 150.0,
          brightness: DynamicTheme.of(context).brightness,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text(assignment.name),
          ),
        ),
      ];
    },
    body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(36),
          topRight: Radius.circular(36),
        ),
      ),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemExtent: 50.0,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
            child: Text('List Item $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]
Based on your use case I think, you don't even need SliverFillRemaining, if you want the list inside SliverFillRemaining to be infinite, just use SliverList with SliverChildBuilderDelegate

```
...
    SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: 50.0,
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
            child: Text('List Item $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    ...
```

previous

You already have your answer in the error, you SliverFillRemaining doesn't use sliver, it uses child which should be widget

```
...
SliverFillRemaining(
    hasScrollBody: true,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(36),
          topRight: Radius.circular(36),
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //adding this line will disable the scrolling and listview and so the CustomScrollView should work as a single scroll view
          itemBuilder: (_, __) => ListTile(
            title: Text("Item"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
...
```

Comment: I appreciate this, but now I run into the issue of there being two lists and when I scroll down the infinite list, the SliverAppBar stays in the same position.

Comment: Checkout the update, on SliverFillRemaining set hasScrollBody to true

Comment: Same issue as `hasScrollBody` defaults to true.

Comment: Try the latest fix, just add set physics of ListView inside container as NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() as I have updated.

Comment: Now the SliverAppBar works but the list doesn't go past item 15 when it's supposed to be infinite.

Comment: If the list is suppose to be infinite, why even put it in SliverFillRemaining? Just use the SliverList with SliverChildBuilderDelegate.

If that doesn't work for your use case, sharing the rest of the code might help, understand, what you exactly want to achieve.